# How to change the % on top each bar to just number?

Tags: excel, excel-charts

[image]

I want to change the % to just number on top of each bar. For example, 62.0% would just be shown as 62. What "custom format code" would I need to put in for this ? I would really appreciate if anyone could help with this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the names are in English but "label alternatives" perhaps?
Look at the image and click on the correct buttons and I guess you will get there.

[image]

Where the arrow is you can customize the labels how you want.
Or if that fails you might have to change the values in the table that the chart is connected to.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Possible my question was specific enough I am actually looking for the custom format code that you have marked as well.

Comment: I assume your setting is "percent", if you change it to Text then it should take the values as they are from the table.